# "E: Package 'ipython' has no installation candidate" while trying to install torch

Tags: apt, software-installation, ipython

I'm trying to install [torch](https://web.archive.org/web/20200213080518/http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html) on  Ubuntu 20.04.

When I run:

```
cd ~/torch; bash install-deps;
```

it generates this error:

```
Package ipython is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ipython' has no installation candidate
```

How do I install ipython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have `pip` installed on your machine, `ipython` can be installed like this:

```
pip3 install ipython
```

If `pip` is not installed, you’ll need to do this first:

```
sudo apt install -y python3-pip
```

That should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

First solution(via apt):
The newest ipython deb version download:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ipython/ipython_5.8.0-1_all.deb

Then install it via apt:

```
sudo apt install /dir/to/ipython_5.8.0-1_all.deb
```

NOTE:

I think it's not the best solution, but it is worth a try.

Second solution via apt(easy):

```
sudo apt install python3-ipython
```

Answer (score -1):

Run:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And add these lines.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe
```

Press Ctrl+O to save the file. Press Ctrl+X to quit nano.

Comment: Adding lines can lead to duplicate entries. It is not a good solution.