# "E: Unable to locate package libqt4-dev" while trying to install torch (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: apt, 22.04, lua

I'm trying to install [torch](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html) for the `image` package of lua. When I run `bash install-deps` command, I get this error:

```
...
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rock-core/qt4/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Some portion of the update is failed
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'git' instead of 'git-core'
Note, selecting 'libncurses-dev' instead of 'ncurses-dev'
Package ipython is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package libqt4-dev
E: Package 'ipython' has no installation candidate
```

I added Qt4 libraries PPA using the answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274134/cannot-install-qt-4-on-ubuntu-20-04-quite-universal-circuit-simulator-qucs), but when I run these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqtcore4 libqtgui4
```

I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libqtcore4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libqt5core5a:i386 libqt5core5a qtchooser:i386 qtchooser

Package libqtgui4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package qt4-dev-tools
E: Unable to locate package libqt4-dev
E: Package 'libqtcore4' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libqtgui4' has no installation candidate
```

---

Also mentioning that I installed `ipython` according to the answer of this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298398/e-package-ipython-has-no-installation-candidate-while-trying-to-install-tor), but I still get the error.

Comment: Notice it is possible to complie qt4 on current ubuntu/debian just doing few changes in Qt4.8.7 sources to be compatible with current g++ version

Comment: see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/147356/how-to-compile-qt-4-8-7-under-debian-bookworm-and-bullseye to know how I compiled Qt 4.8.7 on a Pi 5 under Bookworm and a Pi4 under Bullseye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think these errors are related to whether you installed "ipython" or not. I got the same error("**Unable to locate package libqt4-dev**") while installing "libqt4-dev"(I wanna use qt5 and my environment is **Ubuntu22.04** too). The solution I found was to add a new "add-apt-repository":

```
$sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/ppa
$sudo apt-get update
```

then run the command:

```
$sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqtcore4 libqtgui4
```

I hope this is helpful for you.